# How to solve the certificate issue while connecting to AWS Windows Server via RDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp, windows-server

I'm new to AWS, I've created an EC2 instance with Windows Server 2022 type.

however, I got the following error when I connected to it via RDP:

"The remote computer could not be authenticated due to problems with its security certificate. it may be unsafe to proceed"

"The certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority"

[image]

how can I solve this Certificate issue? because I'm going to use it for development and so input sensitive data to it (like passwords, ...etc). So securing the connection by fixing the certificate issue is so important for me.

Comment: Why do you think this is an issue?

Comment: @Paolo because if the certificate is not trusted then the connection is not secure. right?